# Conversion to JSON from Java

Tags: java, json

I want to open a file in java which contains information in certain pattern and I want to convert that into JSON format. How do I do that?

Comment: posting your file pattern is a good start.

Comment: This post should help 

[Json Libraries options][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using gson

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

It is fast, reliable, and very easy to use. This will allow you to do any java to json to java operation you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind). It can do {de,}serialization and has an unparalleled ability to manipulate JSON data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the org.json jar available in the Maven Repository: 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20090211

You can read about the various components (data-structures and tools) here:
http://json.org/java/

You can also find the links to the Javadocs for them in the above website